# How to read HTML tag values in C# Razor View

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, c#-4.0, razor

I have a value in my span, which i want to compare with C# variable, is it possible ?? If yes, then How ??

I can get the Html tag values in Jquery variable, but still not succeeding to get it to compare it with a C# variable value in Razor View.

```
HTML Tag: <span style="visibility: hidden" id="category">"Some Value"</span>
```

C# Razor Syntax :

```
@foreach (var item in Model.InventoryViewModel.Items.Where(i => i.Category == "HTML Value"))
            {
// Some Code
}
```

I am trying to match the value in span with C# variable, any help suggestions please :\ !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

no idea what you are doing but you could use a variable or something, or even better a property on your view model. Anyway Razor code runs on the server, HTML is on the client so talking about comparing HTML values in Razor is like the chicken and egg problem.

So you could generate your pan tag with a value of your view model:

```
<span style="visibility: hidden" id="category">
    @Model.SomeProperty
</span>
```

and then you compare:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.InventoryViewModel.Items.Where(i => i.Category == Model.SomeProperty))
{            
    // Some Code
}
```

but even better would be to perform this on the controller action and directly filter the collection so that all you have to do in the view is:

```
@foreach (var item in Model.InventoryViewModel.FilteredItems)
{
    // Some Code
}
```

or even shorter using templates:

```
@Html.EditorFor(x => x.InventoryViewModel.FilteredItems)
```

Comment: The thing is i have two models on Viewpage. I am not matching the properties of the same model.

Comment: In this case simply adapt your view model so that it matches the requirements of your view. It's what view models are designed for.

Comment: i have 100 items in model A , i select one from it, and i am trying to get values from the model B based on the value, i selected from Model A. And i have all the items present in both the models in Viewpage. Hope that may give you a better idea, what i am trying to do.

Comment: And Yeah, i dont want to post the page back for some reasons. :\ Otherwise i could have simplied the problem a lot.

Comment: All I can say is that you should change the structure of the view model that you are passing to this view.